# get_user_pages_fast() from kernel thread

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I need to call `get_user_pages_fast()` from a kernel thread. But `get_user_pages_fast()` uses `current->mm` internally, which is set to `NULL` for kernel thread. Is there any way to get around this? The kernel thread in question is working on behalf of another process, say `x`, would it be be fine to just set `x->mm` to `current->mm` and invoke `get_user_pages_fast()`?

**[EDIT 1]**: I verified this and it seems to be working. I am still concerned if it could break in some cases. Any insight is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You are going to need to say what language you are attempting to use

Comment: This being linux kernel, I am using C. Just in case I didn't frame correctly, its not a programming question(like if assignment work) but whether it will be appropriate in context of Linux kernel and kernel thread.

Comment: Assigning `x->mm` to `current->mm` tells the Kernel that your thread has the same virtual memory space than process `x`. Is this really what you want ? (It would bother me to have a kernel thread, which should stay in a pure kernel context to have a virtual memory space ?!)

Comment: @Rerito, yes, this is what I intend here. The kernel thread is either working on address space of process X or handle TCP stream connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced this is totally safe.  The `_fast` part of `get_user_pages_fast` means that acquiring `mm->mmap_sem` is not required, and part of the reason that works is because it is assumed that we are running within the process itself (so eg the `current->mm` can't go away completely).  Since you're running in another thread, you're susceptible to races if the real process ever does something that changes its mapping.

I guess the question is why can't you just use `get_user_pages` instead?

Comment: All the user process needs to do is ``fork`` or ``exit`` while the ``kthread`` is running and there will be more serious monkey business than race conditions to contend with. I agree that better to call ``get_user_pages`` setting ``mm`` directly.

Comment: Roland, @Jonathan Ben-Avraham, thanks guys, I understand the risk now. I'll explore on using get_user_pages() instead of above hack.

Answer (score 2):

Your "hack" will indeed work, but let's take a step back and understand what the idea of it is:

When you are in a kernel thread, (And I am talking about a pure kernel thread (child of kthreadd), not a user thread executing in kernel mode, as would be the case of servicing a syscall), there *is* no user memory to speak of. This is why current->mm is null: There is no "current" user space memory.

When you assign current->mm to x->mm you are "cheating" by annexing the process memory space of the innocent x to be your own. As a consequence, any allocation you perform will be charged to x, and will be visible by x (it is, after all, part of its memory space). Also, there might be internal kernel checks on current->mm which might be tricked, leading to your kernel mode thread to be treated by the kernel as if it were a user mode thread (though arguably other checks rely on KERNEL_DS/USER_DS, which you're not modifying). Still, a concern. This will break if x ever dies (hey - nobody's immortal), and will likely cause an oops, if not a panic altogether.

You haven't said WHY you need to get user pages - if the case is that you know x is alive and you are doing this as part of, say, IPC/shmem, I can see a reason for that. If that is the case, you might want to provide some API for the process in question to "register" with the kernel thread. Otherwise, your solution works, but is.. well, not as neat as it could be.

Comment: @Technologygeeks, yes I am sure that X is alive. WHY - kernel thread finds out that particular page of X is not in memory and needs to map a page. Thats why it uses get_user_page_fast() to allocate a new page.